# How to Convert object into array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, destructuring

I'm having object like this,

```
  const rolePermission = {
    adminView: true,
    adminCreate: true,
    adminDelete: true,
    userView: true,
    userEdit: true,
    userDelete: false,
  };
```

i expecting like this,

```
   const rolePermission = [
    { role: "admin", action: ["View", "Create", "Delete"] },
    { role: "user", action: ["View", "Edit"] },
  ];
```

Comment: You showed your expected output; what's your actual output and the code that produced it? SO isn't a coding service; include your attempt and we'll answer specific questions about it.

Comment: The simple version : check the first object and push to the array

Answer (score 2):

1. Iterate over the object with [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement).
2. Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to split each key into a role, and an action, and [match the key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with that. Create an empty object to update.
3. If the empty object doesn't have a key that matches the current role, [add it, and set it's value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to an object with role and action properties - the action value is an empty array.
4. If the value of the property in the current iteration identified by the key is `true` add that the action to the array.
5. Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the array of objects from the updated object.

```js
const rolePermission={adminView:!0,adminCreate:!0,adminDelete:!0,userView:!0,userEdit:!0,userDelete:!1};

// Match admin or user as one group, and the rest
// of the string as another group
const re = /^(admin|user)(.+)$/;

// Declare temporary working object
const temp = {};

for (const key in rolePermission) {

  // When a match is made the role will be the first
  // element in the returned array, the action the second element
  const [role, action] = key.match(re).slice(1);

  // If the role doesn't exist in the temporary object
  // create it and assign a new default object to it
  temp[role] ??= { role, action: [] };

  // If the property value identified by the key
  // is true push the action to the actions array
  if (rolePermission[key]) {
    temp[role].action.push(action);
  }

}

// Get the array of objects
console.log(Object.values(temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the properties and calculate the result from that.

```js
const rolePermission = { adminView: true, adminCreate: true, adminDelete: true, userView: true, userEdit: true, userDelete: false };

// We want all the entries in `rolePermission`
const intermediate = Object
  .entries(rolePermission)
  .reduce((result, [key, enabled]) => {
    // Split the entry's key into the role and action, using a positive lookahead.
    const [role, action] = key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

    // If the action is enabled,
    if (enabled) {
      // Make sure the action array exists,
      result[role] = result[role] || [];
      // And add the current action to it.
      result[role].push(action);
    }

    return result;
  }, {});

console.log('intermediate:\n', intermediate);

// Now map those entries to the desired output format.
const permissions = Object
  .entries(intermediate)
  .map(([role, action]) => ({ role, action }));

console.log('result:\n', permissions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to get two match groups of role and action using the key of your object and do the filtering based on the value. Rest is how you get the desired output using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

This would also work:

```js
const rolePermission = {
  adminView: true,
  adminCreate: true,
  adminDelete: true,
  userView: true,
  userEdit: true,
  userDelete: false,
};

const output = Object.entries(
  Object.entries(rolePermission)
    .map(([key, allowed]) => {
      const regex = new RegExp("(.*)(View|Edit|Create|Delete)", "g");
      const [, role, action] = regex.exec(key)
      return [role, action, allowed];
    }).filter(([,,allowed]) => allowed)
    .reduce((prev, [role, action]) => {
      prev[role] = prev[role] ? prev[role].concat([action]) : [action];
      return prev;
    }, {})
).map(([role, action]) => ({ role, action }));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Excessively convoluted, and new actions would require updating the regex.

Comment: @Cerbrus, tbh we cannot even depend on upper-case letters too (in case the action is two words) as in your answer. This is just another approach.